# Remote access to Ubuntu Server

Tags: 18.04, server, remote-login

I disabled my ufw firewall in the morning(for pinging purpose). In the afternoon, I enabled it again. However, I can't access to the Ubuntu Server remotely after enabled the firewall. What are the possible reasons? Firewall?

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Connection Timed Out" may indeed suggest a firewall configured to ignore your attempt to connect.

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo ufw status`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues. You're not connecting to the Windows PC. The Windows firewall needs to allow ssh tcp/22 open. Try using '-v' to get more information about the connection and authentication status.

Also the path needs to be in a different format. You cannot use backslashes. A non-quoted backslash, , is used as an escape character in Bash.

Try this command.

> scp -v test.txt Student@192.168.179.4:C:/Users/Student/Desktop

Rather than using 192.168.179.4, use the correct ip address.

Also, the keys need to be setup correctly.

Also, check out:
http://woshub.com/using-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-windows/

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks!! I realised that I used the wrong ip addrress.

Comment: I would love an up vote..